# Dependency injection tradeoff between constructor and template parameters in C++?

Tags: c++, dependency-injection

I would like to know **when to use** dependency injection via **constructor** and when to use **template parameters**.

#### Example

I have the following *class definitions*:

1. `Interface`:

```cpp
/// Interface class
class Interface {
 public:
  virtual void Method() = 0;
  virtual ~Interface() = default;
};
```

2. `Concrete`:

```cpp
/// Concrete class
class Concrete : public Interface {
 public:
  void Method() override { std::cout << "Concrete.Method()\n"; }
  static void StaticMethod() { std::cout << "Concrete.StaticMethod()\n"; }
};
```

3. `ConstructorDI` with dependecy on an `Interface` via constructor:

```cpp
/// Class with constructor dependency injection
class ConstructorDI {
 public:
  explicit ConstructorDI(Interface &interface) : interface_(interface) {
    std::cout << "** ConstructorDI() **" << std::endl;
    // Call the Method() exposed by the interface
    interface_.Method();
  }

 private:
  // Interface-based dependency (this class doesn't own the underlying concrete
  // type)
  Interface &interface_;
};
```

4. `TemplateDI` with dependency on `typename T`

```cpp
/// Class with template dependency injection
template <typename T>
class TemplateDI {
 public:
  TemplateDI() { 
      std::cout << "** TemplateDI() **" << std::endl;
      // Call the Method()
      t_.Method(); 
      // Call the StaticMethod()
      T::StaticMethod();
}

 private:
  // Type-based dependency (this class owns the concrete type)
  // Thus, cannot be a Interface (pure abstract) class
  T t_;
};
```

A typical use of the above would be the following [example](https://godbolt.org/z/ajnMnGs6W):

```cpp
// Concrete class implementing the Interface class
Concrete concrete;

// Create a class using dependency injection via constructor
ConstructorDI constructor_d_i(concrete);

// Create a class using dependency injection via template
TemplateDI<Concrete> template_d_i;
```

which produces the following output:

```
** ConstructorDI() **
Concrete.Method()
** TemplateDI() **
Concrete.Method()
Concrete.StaticMethod()
```

#### Observations

- The above example shows that the *constructor dependency* route allows dependency on a concrete type not owned by the class itself.
- A *template-based* dependency injection allows a class to own a concrete type, but can also be used to depend on static methods.

#### Questions

To make a tradeoff between the two types I would like to know:

- Is there another method of dependency injection in C++ I'm missing?
- Is there a major difference when it comes to testability?
- When should I use the one or the other, e.g. as stated in the observations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same trade off that using templates versus inheritance-based polymorphism always has: template instantiation happens at compile time and thus allows compile time polymorphic behavior.

Inheritance-based polymorphism happens at runtime. You can therefore, for example, store a collection of pointers to objects that you do not know the types of at compile time e.g.

```
//...
std::vector<Interface*> some_stuff = get_heterogeneous_concrete_types();
std::vector<ConstructorDI> di_objects;
std::transform(some_stuff.begin(), some_stuff.end(), std::back_inserter(di_objects),
    [](auto* p) { return ConstructorDI(*p); }
);
//...
```

You can't do the above if you have multiple DI types that are parametrized on the concrete types. But if you don't need that kind of behavior the templated version will be more efficient, etc.

Comment: Thus, in short the tradeoff depends on **compile-time** (Template) vs **runtime** (Inheritance-based) dependency injection, where **compile-time** is more efficient. That's a clear answer.